# What is this old font like Pacman or Modern Plate from real estate agency?

Tags: font-identification

i'm not really sure if i can ask it, but i'm looking for this font for days now.
It is very similar to Modern Plate or font of Pacman title, but with stripes.
I'm sure I've seen it in a famous logo and anyone I showed it gave the same impression.
It's something really old.

I've already tried search it with:
WhatTheFont,What Font Is and Identifont without success.

The attached image represent "Agenzia", it's from resources of an old SWF.
[image]

This is the complete title "Agenzia Immobiliare":
[image]

Can someone help me to find this font or recognize it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15):

[Dafont's Simulata](http://www.dafont.com/simulata.font?text=AGENZIA&fpp=100&back=theme) seems to be a good match. Apparently some shadow effect has been used to make it bi-coloured in your example.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is very close, but I see some discrepancies - for instance, the shading distribution on the Z is reversed with regard to the Z in Simone's example, and Simulata's B lacks the protrusion at lower left. The author of Simulata may be able to shed some light on whether Simone's example is an earlier version... I'm going to email him.

Comment: @recognizer when it comes to logo design there is always a strong possibility that the designer started with a font then made some modifications to make it somewhat unique. You might not find an exact match for the logo as that seems to be the case here.

Comment: @recognizer This could simply be an artifact of the way the "logo" was produced - it looks like it was rendered in off-white on a brown background at a low resolution, and then very roughly cut out of that background (note the differences between the four`I` letters, or the two `M`s.)

Comment: This all may be moot, anyway, as I've dug a little deeper in the Simulata author's site, and he notes that it's based on Sinaloa, the fond @johnlewisdesign points out in his answer: http://www.theboutons.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=79768:additional-free-typefaces&catid=52:boutype&Itemid=393 Given the age of Sinaloa, it seems far more likely that anything similar which we might find in a SWF file is, at its root, based on Sinaloa.

Comment: @recognizer The same concern applies to Sinaloa, of course, but I'm at this point absolutely convinced that any odd protrusions are an artifact of the clumsy way the letters were cut out.

Answer (score 14):

It's Sinaloa, I think originally struck by URW, and then licensed to Lettraset in the mid 1990s, and distributed under the Fontek brand.

Simulata is also very close match— I'm jesting...**I** created Simulata, and as the credits say on Dafont, it's donationware. Use it commercially or privately when you've given a few bucks to a good charity, or do something else good for our world like picking up some roadside discarded stuff on Earth Day. Honor System, Good Karma Be Yours.

The short of it is I recreated the font because at the time there was no Windows version. Sorry for the side-tracking.

It's Sinaloa and someone just smooshed the lettering.

My Best,

Gary David Bouton

Comment: Good work Gary :) I remember having a sheet of rub down lettering of this back in the day!

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 6):

It is Sinaloa, an old Letraset font from 1974 by Rosmarie Tissi:

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Sinaloa+CG/

[image]

Comment: Is it allowed to add an picture of this code here? If yes please do it (suppose the given link is broken ...)